# Proper NSActionCell programming

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscell, nscontrol

I'm having trouble finding information about custom controls and cells.

My control should have multiple `NSCell`s, which is why I can't use the default `NSControl`.
The Cell is being displayed correctly. 
However, they are `NSButtonCells`, and should respond to a mouse down.

This is what I've tried:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self.testCell trackMouse:theEvent inRect:[self frameForTestCell] ofView:self untilMouseUp:NO];
}
```

I have no idea if this is the right approach, but I didn't find some proper resources...